# Unexpected behaviour of QGraphicsScene when trying to add fixed-size Items

Tags: python, qt, qgraphicsscene, pyside6, qgraphicsitem

I add Items to a GraphicsScene which should appear in a fix size on screen independent of zooming in and out.
I create them in the following manner:

```py
class LocationGraphicsItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, coordinate, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        x = coordinate[0]
        y = -coordinate[1]
        self.setRect(-5, -5, 10, 10)
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.setFlag(self.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIgnoresTransformations)
```

I add them to the scene like this:

```py
coordinate = (3412770.9, 5358376.3)
item = LocationGraphicsItem(coordinate)
my_scene.addItem(item)
item.ensureVisible()
```

and later call

```py
my_view.fitInView(my_scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

on my view.
As long as I add all of them before the Qt eventloop is started, the view is set to display the correct scope, the scene figures out the correct  `sceneRect` which is something like:

```
PySide6.QtCore.QRectF(3412765.400000, -5371895.600000, 82420.600000, 13524.800000)
```

However, if I add items after the eventloop is started and the `QGraphicsView` is already visible, my region of interest is cramped in the top right corner, as the `sceneRect` changes to:

```
PySide6.QtCore.QRectF(-5.500000, -5371895.600000, 3495191.500000, 5371901.100000)
```

How can I avoid that? Can someone explain to me why this happens?
I know that I can calculate the relevant rectangle newly with `my_scene.itemsBoundingRect()`, which unfortunately is quite slow.

What are alternatives / best practices to implement a fixed-size marker? I would prefer to specify the size in pixels anyway.

---

Here's some complete code:

```py
import random
import sys
print("Python: ", sys.version)
import PySide6
print("PySide: ", PySide6.__version__)
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LocationGraphicsItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, coordinate, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        x = coordinate[0]
        y = -coordinate[1]
        self.setRect(-5, -5, 10, 10)
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("blue"))
        self.setFlag(self.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIgnoresTransformations)

def add_something():
    print(scene.sceneRect())
    point =(3.4e6+random.random()*1e5, 5.3e6+random.random()*1e5)
    print("Random point: ", point)
    item = LocationGraphicsItem(point)
    scene.addItem(item)
    item.setVisible(True)
    item.ensureVisible()
    view.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    print(scene.sceneRect())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_points = [(3412770.9, 5358376.3), (3495180.5, 5371890.1), (3495099.1, 5370624.6), (3485765.4, 5371030.1)]
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    for point in my_points:
        item = LocationGraphicsItem(point)
        scene.addItem(item)
        item.setVisible(True)
        item.ensureVisible()

    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(parent = None)
    window.setGeometry(50, 50, 1300, 750)
    basic_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=window)
    window.setCentralWidget(basic_widget)
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    basic_widget.setLayout(layout)
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("add something", parent = basic_widget)
    button.clicked.connect(add_something)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene, parent = basic_widget)
    layout.addWidget(view)
    view.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    window.setVisible(True)
    app.exec()
```

Output:

```
Python:  3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]
PySide:  6.4.0.1
PySide6.QtCore.QRectF(3412765.400000, -5371895.600000, 82420.600000, 13524.800000)
Random point:  (3449076.7327629146, 5323846.465410875)
PySide6.QtCore.QRectF(-5.500000, -5371895.600000, 3495191.500000, 5371901.100000)
```

Comment: The `sceneRect` is *never* affected by transformations of any kind (view or items) since it's either explicitly set or only includes the largest *bounding rect* of all items, eventually expanding if required (but never shrinking it). You say that you get different results from `sceneRect()` (but never specified if it's that of the scene or of the view), which can only happen if the rect has been explicitly set (on the view or the scene) or bounding rects of items affect it. Please provide a comprehensive [mre] to allow us to understand what you're doing, and also ease up testing on our part.

Comment: To clarify the `sceneRect` aspect above: an item's bounding rect is always in local coordinates, and completely ignoring any transformation (including local transforms like `rotation()`); this also includes possible "wrong" bounding rects for items that include the pen width even if the transformation will (or won't) affect the pen width. This means that you shall never completely rely only on item bounding rects to compute the view's scene rect in case the view applies transforms (like `fitInView()`) and/or the item has the `ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag set.

Comment: @musicamante, FYI see my answer.

Comment: @relent95 Thanks, I wasn't able to check that as the OP didn't provide a MRE, so I had to make assumptions based on the known behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a Qt bug. Why not report it? (See [Report Bugs](https://wiki.qt.io/Reporting_Bugs).)

You can remedy it by calling the `QGraphicsItem.sceneTransform()` manually like the following.

```
def add_something():
    ...
    item = LocationGraphicsItem(point)
    scene.addItem(item)
    ...
    dummy = item.sceneTransform()
    view.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    ...
```

Comment: Interesting, that should *not* happen (at least, theoretically, and based on the docs), but I can vaguely understand why it *may* happen: due to the complex way items are added and then processed (which is done in "lazy" mode, as QGraphicsScene may virtually process thousands of items, including their additions). It seems like the call to `sceneTransform()` allows the scene boundary computation to take precedence considering the whole constructed item (including pos and transforms), which normally happens some time after that, causing the scene rect to be changed inconsistently.

Comment: After some digging, I found a related bug report: [QTBUG-19039 - Adding a QGraphicsPixmapItem with ItemIgnoresTransformations causes sceneRect to extend to 0,0](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19039). Unfortunately, even if it has been reported in 2011 (and for Qt4!), it's still unresolved, so I doubt that it will be fixed anytime soon. I don't know if I'll have enough time to dig more into this in the next days, but, if you can, maybe consider doing some research and eventually add a comment to that report with a suggestion about your workaround.

Comment: I added `self.sceneTransform()` at the end of the  `__init__` of my custom fixed size GraphicItems, which solved the problem for me.